# Need help for redirecting encoded URL with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect the URL from

```
https://www.example.com/%3fetcc_cmp%3dgmb%26etcc_med%3dseo
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/?etcc_cmp=GMB&etcc_med=SEO
```

and I can't find a working solution.

The following isn't working at all:

```
Redirect permanent /%3fetcc_cmp%3dgmb%26etcc_med%3dseo https://www.example.com/?etcc_cmp=GMB&etcc_med=SEO
```

How can I solve this with `.htaccess`?

Comment: Please do add your tried htaccess rules file in your question as its highly encouraged on SO for questioners to add their efforts, thank you.

Comment: Same as RewriteRule, the Redirect directive matches against the already URL-decoded path component of the URL. So you would actually need to match `?etcc_cmp=gmb&etcc_med=seo` here.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Redirect permanent /%3fetcc_cmp%3dgmb%26etcc_med%3dseo https://www.example.com/?etcc_cmp=GMB&etcc_med=SEO
> ```

As noted in comments, the `Redirect` directive matches against the URL-decoded (ie. %-decoded) URL-path, so you would need to rewrite it like the following instead:

```
Redirect 302 /?etcc_cmp=gmb&etcc_med=seo https://www.example.com/?etcc_cmp=GMB&etcc_med=SEO
```

I was going to suggest using a backreference (with a `RedirectMatch` directive instead) to capture the URL-path that needs to become the query string, but it would seem the source and target are not the same (differing in the case of the URL parameter values).

Note that if you have existing mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule`) directives then you may need to use mod_rewrite instead to avoid conflicts.

NB: You cannot do this in `.htaccess` on a Windows server since the `?` (encoded as `%3f`) is not permitted in Windows filenames. You will get a 403 Forbidden *before* `.htaccess` is able to process the request. On Windows you will need to do this directly in the server  config (*before* the request is mapped to the filesystem).